# Holes appear in image after rotating and scaling it c++ SDL

Tags: c++, image, matrix, rotation, sdl-2

I've got an interesting problem. I'm using matrix multiplication to rotate and scale my images for my game. It works great when I scale the image down by half or more, but if the image stays its original size holes start to appear. I've attached some images of the problem below. My drawing code is below as well.

### Before rotation

[image: Before rotation]

### After rotation

[image: After rotation]

### Drawing code

```
void Graphics::drawImage(Graphics::Image i, float x, float y, float rot, float xScale, float yScale)
{
    unsigned char r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
    Vector<float> pos = Vector<float>::create(0, 0);

    i.setRotation(rot);
    i.setXScale(xScale);
    i.setYScale(yScale);

    for (int j = 0; j < i.getWidth() * i.getHeight(); j++)
    {
        i.getPixel((j % i.getWidth()), (j / i.getWidth()), r, g, b);
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, r, g, b, 255);
        pos.elements[0] = (j % i.getWidth());
        pos.elements[1] = (j / i.getWidth());

        Vector<float> transPos = pos - Vector<float>::create(i.getCenterX(), i.getCenterY());
        Matrix<float> trans = math::scale<float>(i.getXScale(), i.getYScale()) * math::rot<float>((double)i.getRot());
        transPos = math::mult<float, float>(trans, transPos);

        SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, (int)x + transPos.elements[0] + (i.getCenterX() * i.getXScale()), (int)y + transPos.elements[1] + (i.getCenterY() * i.getYScale()));

    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you keep drawing the image by iterating trough points? SDL has functions for it.

Comment: I don't suppose this is how one rasterises rotated image (while it probably can be done with trickier rounding, it certainly not worth it). You can use [SDL_RenderCopyEx](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderCopyEx) to do proper rendering, which will also be a lot faster.